# How can I do this in a scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, scope

I have this scope:

```
scope :search, lambda {|q| where("name LIKE ?", "%#{q}%") }
```

However, I want to compare `q` and `name` irregardless of capitalization. So I can do `#{q.downcase}` but how can I get `name` lowercased?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the SQL `lower` function:

```
scope :search, lambda {|q| where("LOWER(name) LIKE ?", "%#{ q.downcase }%") }
```